# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined - Angular Unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-unit-test

I'm trying to write a unit test and I'm getting this error.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined at Jasmine`

```js
const mockServiceObj = jasmine.createSpyObj < FormRegistrationService > (["registerForm", "pipe"]);
const getCurrentSystemPreference = jasmine.createSpyObj < CurrentSystemPreferencesService > ([
    "getCurrentSystemPreference",
    "pipe",
]);

function getServiceManagerLinks(): ServiceManagerSharedLinksComponent {
    return new ServiceManagerSharedLinksComponent(null, mockServiceObj, getCurrentSystemPreference);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: A bit unusual unit test (at least for me). However, you're just mocking methods but returning nothing, thus `undefined`. You should return value with just `createSpy('spyName', 'getCurrentSystemPreference').and.returnValue(of({}));`

Comment: @GytisTG Thank you for the comment, yes it's quite unusual. I just posted a screenshot above, with the error that I received, how would I fix that? Thank you again for your help, Gytis.

Comment: I have provided a working minimal example. You may need to change/update a few things in your app since not all code parts are visible. But the main idea should remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the correct (or at least close to correct) unit tests approach for your situation.

You have `currentSystemPreferencesService` const and provide it to `providers`. Now it's accessible in all tests cases. You also provide `getPreferences` field as callable method. And `of(true)` means you return on `Observable` which is needed for `pipe()` in real code since you immediately call `.pipe(...)` after calling `getPreferences(SystemPreference.APITestValue)`

```
describe('ServiceManagerSharedLinksComponent ', () => {
  let component: ServiceManagerSharedLinksComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ServiceManagerSharedLinksComponent>;

  const currentSystemPreferencesService: any = {
    getPreferences: () => of(true),
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ServiceManagerSharedLinksComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: FormRegistrationService,
          useValue: {}, // <-- You will need a different const for registerForm() method
        },
        {
          provide: CurrentSystemPreferencesService,
          useValue: currentSystemPreferencesService,
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ServiceManagerSharedLinksComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should set display owner info when showOwnerInfo is TRUE', () => {
    expect(component.isDisplayOwnerInfoSetOnSystemPreference).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```